# Generalising the Mayer-Vietoris principle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology

My understanding of the general Mayer-Vietoris principle is as follows.  We want to compute the cohomology of some sheaf $\mathscr{F}$.  We start by taking a resolution $$\mathscr{F}_0 \rightarrow \mathscr{F}_1 \rightarrow \mathscr{F}_2 \rightarrow \cdots$$ of $\mathscr{F}$ by acyclic sheaves, then replace each $\mathscr{F}_i$ functorially by a resolution of its space of global sections in order to get a double complex, and finally construct the two resulting spectral sequences.  One of these spectral sequences tells you that the total complex computes the cohomology of $\mathscr{F}$, whilst the other hopefully reduces to some simpler things you might already know about.

In practice (in topology, which is what I'm really interested in), $\mathscr{F}$ may be a (locally) constant sheaf, and the $\mathscr{F}_i$ the sheaves of singular or de Rham $i$-cochains, although of course one could consider much more general things.  However, the resolutions of the global sections always seem to be of the same form, namely the Čech complex for some open cover (perhaps this is what is really meant by the name "Mayer-Vietoris").

Are there other resolutions that give useful spectral sequences?  For instance, you could take the global sections of the Godement resolutions of the $\mathscr{F}_i$, but it's not clear to me that this would ever be a sensible thing to do.

Comment: What do you mean by a resolution of the space of global sections? Resolution of the constant sheaf corresponding to this space? It might help if you could provide a familiar example of how the procedure described in the question works.

Comment: For example, if you have a cover of your space $X$ by open sets $U$, $V$, you can resolve $\mathscr{F}_i(X)$ by $\mathscr{F}_i(U) \oplus \mathscr{F}_i(V) \rightarrow \mathscr{F}_i(U \cap V)$.  This is the Čech complex argument I was alluding to.

Comment: This is what I don't understand. ${\mathscr F}_i(X)$ is not a sheaf, it is a value of a sheaf, what do you mean by resolving it?

Comment: I mean resolving it as an abelian group (or as a module over your coefficient ring if applicable).

Comment: Oh I finally see now, thanks. I believe "resolution of the **space** of global sections" is confusing not only for me then...